# Is there any way to remove bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I mistakenly added a bounty to my question on Stack Overflow. Is there any way to remove it? I searched but didn't find any solution/or option to remove bounty.

Comment: Duplicate: [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/187824)

Comment: It is very difficult to add a bounty by mistake - it is a multiple stage process. Do you mean to say you didn't understand that the reputation offered is taken off yours and you now regret it?

Comment: @Oded PEBKAC ;P

Comment: yeah exactly. Actually i just gain privilege of bounty. I just tried to test what actually will be done. and then :(

Comment: @MuneebNasir Don't worry about it, we all do [trial by error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_and_error) once in awhile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag your question for moderation attention and clearly explain that you set the bounty by mistake and you'd like for it to be removed.

Your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928540/haproxxy-running-error) has not yet received any attention from the bounty (it's fairly recent), most likely the moderator responding to your flag will remove it. However, the decision is completely up to the moderator and they might deny your request if they suspect abuse of the bounty system.

In the future please be a bit more careful when using the site's features.